# use function search substring js

Tags: javascript

I want to write a code in the JavaScript language that searches for the number of repetitions of letters in a word, like this code, but in a short way o(n).

```
function naiveSearch(long, short){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < long.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < short.length; j++){
           if(short[j] !== long[i+j]) break;
           if(j === short.length - 1) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
naiveSearch("lorielol loled", "lol")
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done better than O(long.length * short.length)

Comment: It's obviously not possible to be O(1) since it has to look at each character in the two strings at least once.

Comment: give me a solution o(n)

Comment: Use `long.substring(i, i+short.length) == short` in the loop, rather than nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.substring()` or `.slice()` method rather than a nested loop.

```js
function naiveSearch(long, short) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0, limit = long.length - short.length; i < limit; i++) {
    if (long.substring(i, i + short.length) == short) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(naiveSearch("lorielol loled", "lol"));
```

This is still O(n*m). You do O(n) iterations of the main loop, and the substrings and comparisons are each O(m).